# How to fix the imports for java example

Tags: java, opencv, import

I would like to try out an implementation of FloodFill in Java with OpenCV. 
I found an example of it. Too bad it does not recognize the import libraries. 

Basically there are two problems. 

1. I have no idea what those are:

```
import controlP5.ControlP5;

import controlP5.Slider;

import processing.core.PApplet;
```

Is it something written by the author that he uses but does not share?If not how do i install it?

2. I succeded installing OpenCV. But it looks like this

```
import org.opencv.core.*;
```

which is not equal to the example, does it make any difference?

You can see the source code below

```
import java.awt.Point;

import controlP5.ControlP5;
import controlP5.Slider;

import processing.core.PApplet;
import sj.opencv.Capture;
import sj.opencv.CxCore;
import sj.opencv.CxCore.CompareMode;
import sj.opencv.HighGui;
import sj.opencv.ImgProc;
import sj.opencv.IplImage;
import sj.opencv.PUtils;
import sj.opencv.Scalar;
import sj.opencv.Constants.ColorModel;
import sj.opencv.Constants.PixelDepth;

/**
 * @author siggi
 * @date Jul 29, 2010
 */
 public class FloodFill extends PApplet{

    int w = 320;
    int h = 240;

    IplImage im;
    IplImage im_res;
    Capture capture;

    int click_x = w/2;
    int click_y = h/2;

    // Slider values
    Slider low_slider;
    Slider high_slider;

    @Override
    public void setup(){
            size(2*w + 2, h+150);

            // Camera initiated to capture from device
            capture = HighGui.captureFromCAM(0);

            im = CxCore.createImage(w, h, PixelDepth.IPL_DEPTH_8U, ColorModel.BGR);
            im_res = CxCore.createImage(w+2, h+2, PixelDepth.IPL_DEPTH_8U, ColorModel.GRAY);

            // Init GUI
            ControlP5 controlP5 = new ControlP5(this);
            low_slider = controlP5.addSlider("low_val",     0,      10,     5,      20,             h+20,   10,     100);
            high_slider = controlP5.addSlider("high_val",   0,      10,     5,      80,             h+20,   10,     100);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(){
            // When a frame becomes available
            if( HighGui.queryFrame(capture, im) ){
                    background(70);

                    // Draw it
                    image(PUtils.getPImage(im), 0, 0);

                    // Start by clearing the mask (it needs to be cleared for repeatable behavior)
                    CxCore.set(im_res, new Scalar(0), null);

                    // Perform the floodfilling
                    ImgProc.floodFill(im, new Point( click_x, click_y ), new Scalar(low_slider.value()), new Scalar(high_slider.value()), im_res);

                    // This simply changes the mask from being a 0-1 value to 0-255 value for viewing
                    CxCore.cmpS(im_res, 0, im_res, CompareMode.CV_CMP_NOT_EQUAL);

                    image(PUtils.getPImage(im_res), w, 0);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(){
            click_x = mouseX;
            click_y = mouseY;

            if( click_x<0 ) click_x = 0;
            if( click_x>=w ) click_x = w-1;
            if( click_y<0 ) click_x = 0;
            if( click_y>=h ) click_x = h-1;
    }
```

}

Any kind of help would be awesome. Thanks in advance=)

Answer (score 0):

[sj.opencv](https://code.google.com/p/opencv-java/) is a wrapping of openCV and processing, it is not the same as [org.opencv](http://opencv.org/about.html) which is more or less native approach of openCV.

Comment: so in this case, do i need to install sj.opencv additionally?

Comment: It is one of the options, but the sj.opencv is not maintained so I would rather advise to use org.opencv.

Comment: Does sj.opencv offer something special for this example which is not included in org.opencv. Or are they equal in this case because the functionality overlaps here.